# Convert java.util.Date to String in yyyy-MM-dd format without creating a lot of objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I need to convert `java.util.Date` to `String` in `yyyy-MM-dd` format in a big amounts.

I have just moved to java 8 and want to know how to do it properly.
My solution with Java 7 was like:

```
DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN)

DATE_FORMATTER.print(value.getTime())
```

It helped me not to create a lots of redundant objects.

So now when I moved to java 8 I want rewrite it properly but:

```
LocalDate.fromDateFields(value).toString())
```

creates each time new `LocalDate` object and this gives a lot of work to GC.

Are there any ways to solve my problem?
Performance and thread-safety are very important.

After some testing I have found that even with creating new objects construction with:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).format(value))
```

the fastest all over this topic.

Comment: Do you have `Date` or `LocalDate` objects?

Comment: Hi, java.util.Date

Comment: There is no need converting to `LocalDate`, just use the `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: When you said Java 8, I was thinking java.time (the modern Java date and time API), but `LocalDate.fromDateFields(value)` isn’t java.time. It seems to be Joda-Time.

Comment: If you need the speed, do what is fastest. You may hide it behind a nice interface so no one notices unless they need to know. java.time was written for conveniency of use. I don’t think it’s slow, but it does create more objects, and I guess it was a conscious choice to pay this price. For 99+ % of cases I should say it’s worth it, but if you’re in the last percent, accept that as a fact.

Comment: Have you tried using a `ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>`? Depending on the number of threads and unless you plan to use `LocalDate` as your input, that might not be a bad solution. It would reduce garbage collection as every thread will have it's own `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following only has an overhead for the conversion of the old Date to the new LocalDate.

```
    Date date = new Date();
    LocalDate ldate = LocalDate.from(date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    String s = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.format(ldate); // uuuu-MM-dd
```

It is true however that DateTimeFormatters are thread-safe and hence will have one instantiation more per call.

P.S.

I added `.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)` because of a reported exception, and @Flown's solution: specifying the zone. As `Date` is not necessarily used for UTC dates, one might use another one.

Comment: Good idea I didn't notice that I can use `date.toInstant()` already with the static method `LocalDate.from()`, this reduces the part of specifing a time zone. +1

Comment: @Flown You're right also on JDK10 what's the problem?

Comment: @Flown Is `LocalDate.from(date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC))` faster than `date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();`?

Comment: This is left to be tested, but I don't think so.

Comment: Is it better to use DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE instead of DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE?

Comment: @OleksandrRiznyk ISO_DATE has an _optional_ time part, so ISO_LOCAL_DATE is more _efficient,_ however ISO_DATE is a jewel to remember too.

Answer (score 3):

Use SimpleDateFormat to format Date.

watch out, SDF is **NOT THREAD-SAFE**, it might not be important but keep that in mind.

For Example:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println((sdf.format(new Date())).toString());
```

[LINK](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/java-date-string-conversion/) with more information.

Comment: The method parse(String) in the type DateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (Date)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have exact numbers from point of view of the performance but I would use the [Java 8 Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) to solve this issue. In your special case I would use the following statement:

```
LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
```

**EDIT:**
For this solution is a conversion from `java.util.Date` to `java.time.LocalDate` required!

```
new Date().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

Answer (score 2):

Without creating lots of objects, meaning you want the performance version?

```
public static String getIsoDate(java.util.Date time) {
    java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(time);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int year = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int day = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    sb.append(year);
    sb.append('-');
    if (month < 10) {
        sb.append('0');
    }
    sb.append(month);
    sb.append('-');
    if (day < 10) {
        sb.append('0');
    }
    sb.append(day);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This version is thread-safe and avoids most hidden object creations, and unless you have years under 1000 or over 9999, it will print just fine.

Comment: This isn't offensive it's actually interest, are you sure that this code is _faster_ than converting it to `LocalDate` and using the Java 8 Time API? I mean, I'm definetly not a performance freak, but it seems that this is a lot of code with memory allocation... Seems to be interesting...

Comment: There's also a lot of memory allocation in the conversion to LocalDate and using the default ISO8601 formatter. It's just a few calls deeper than we see here, and it still relies on Calander, because that's the only way to get the correct data. Also, I've made a tiny mistake, because it gives 0-based months. I'll edit it right away.

Comment: Correction: the Java 8 API converts the epoch time value to convert to Instant, then you'd need to convert to ZonedDateTime or OffsetDateTime and extract the LocalDate from it. The allocation operations a comparable, until you get to the printing.

Comment: This is almost exactly how I did it in an app which did shedloads of date processing, and it greatly reduced the rate of garbage collections.
I'd suggest two further improvements which can avoid all memory allocations entirely:
1) Reuse the Calendar by getting it from a ThreadLocal.  (That ensures thread-safety without creating more than one for each thread.)
2) Instead of returning a String, accept a StringBuilder and simply append the date to that.  Much of the time, the date is going to be part of a bigger string, and so this will avoid creating either a String or a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

you can use @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") annotation on your field.