# Convert Date format in Java

Tags: java, spring-rest

I have a Date object in DTO object:

```
public class TopTerminalsDTO {

    private Date date;

    private int volume;

    private int count;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(int volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

When I get the response in Angular I get

```
count: 1
date: "2018-10-06T00:00:00.000+0000"
volume: 111
```

I want to get this date format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` in Angular.

What is the proper way to convert the Date into the DTO object? Is it better to use LocalDateTime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert java.util.Date to String in yyyy-MM-dd format without creating a lot of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52870774/convert-java-util-date-to-string-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format-without-creating-a-lot-of)

Comment: Can you add the relevant part i mean where and how are you setting date in `TopTerminalsDTO `?

Comment: If you're using Spring Web or whatever, you need to make it clear in your question.

Comment: side note: not use Date class instead of use new class LocalDate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688736/are-java-util-date-and-java-util-calendar-deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use DateFormat to convert your desire date format.

```
TopTerminalsDTO tt = new TopTerminalsDTO();
tt.setDate(new Date());
String strDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);
String formattedDate= dateFormat.format(tt.getDate());
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

As you are sending rest object to angular so u can use string field as date in DTO once covert it in desire date format.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use LocalDateTime object, but it will return it with a T between the date and hours. You should remove it like in the selected answer here [LocalDate - How to remove character 'T' in LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337487/localdate-how-to-remove-character-t-in-localdate)

Answer (score 1):

User the Below Code.

```
Date myDate = new Date();
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format(myDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

`LocalDate` is the preferred way of many developers since it's been released in Java 8. You can format a `LocalDate` object the way you want by using the `.format(DateTimeFormatter)` method of `LocalDate`.

Like this example from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
String text = date.format(formatter);
LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(text, formatter);
```

**Edit**:

The `LocalDate` class doens't provide a time representation. Therefore if you like to also have time, use the `LocalDateTime` class. The `.format()` method of `LocalDateTime` can be used like the `.format()` method of `LocalDate` as shown above.

Comment: But I need hours and minutes. With LocalDate I get date: "2018-11-06" only.

Comment: I added additional ifnormation about `LocalDateTime`. You can use this to also have a time representation in your field. The formatter works the same as with `LocalDate`.